# Difference between "!" and "." operator

Tags: vba, operators

What is the exact difference between the vba operators `!` and `.` ?

I have noticed that often they can be used interchangable, but sometimes one works and one doesn't (Forms-Collection in Access e.g.)

Aswell, when you accidentially write `!optSomething` (some optionbuttion) instead of `Not optSomething` withing a `with` clause, it will not break at compile but at runtime, because `!` is used - my company had some broken vba after `On Error Resume Next` with this, and i only realised when having "brake on every error" activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `!` character invisibly calls the default member for that object.

For a Recordset, the default member is the Fields method, and the default member of a field object is the Value property, so these lines are identical:

```
sEmp = rst.Fields("emp_id")
sEmp = rst.Fields("emp_id").Value
sEmp = rst!emp_id
```

So, the reason you'll see it work for some objects and not others, is probably because those objects don't have the default member that you expect.